# What is the reason for the ban call as a member of a pointer without an explicit object (even in non-static member function)?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Consider a following code snippet:

```
struct C
{
   void (C::*m)();
   void f();
   void g(); 
   ...
};
```

If we want to call member function by pointer-to-member from another member-function we need to do this by explicit use of `this` keyword:

```
void C::f()
{ 
    m = &C::g;
    g(); // works well w/o explicit `this`
    this->g(); // also works good
    (this->*m)(); // ok
    m(); // not allowed w/o object... why?
}
```

On the last line i've got an error:
`error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((C*)this)->C::m (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((C*)this)->C::m) (...)'`

Why (what is the reason to forbid) not allowed to call member function by pointer-to-member from another member function w/o explicit object (and must use binary operators '.*' or '->*' only)?

Comment: Member functions are *members* of something. A pointer to a member function is just a pointer, without any information of any *object instance* needed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think you are missing the point. `g()` is a member function but it can be called without *explicitly* writing `this->g()`, hence OP wonders why the implicit `this->` can not be used for the member function pointer `m` as well.

Comment: @alexolut Maybe there is no reason, it's just as it is. Member function pointers are not really used very often, the standard thus might simply not add more wording and complexity by dealing with this case. Normal member function calls happen way more often, so they are better supported by making them more convenient.

Comment: @DanielFrey Because `g` *is* a member function, the `this->` part is *implicit*, the compiler adds it automatically. Because `m` is a pointer to a member function, how would the compiler know that it should use `this` and not some other object instance?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And `m` is a member as well. I don't think it would be a problem to use implicit `this->` technically, it's more of a decision to not do so. Anyways, those "why does the standard"-question are often not answerable in a definite way.

Comment: @DanielFrey The point is that a member function is not the same as a *pointer* to a member function. Why did the specification authors didn't allow implicit `this->` for pointer to member functions? There's probably a rationale somewhere in old discussions,

Comment: After some thought, i decide that it might be due to the fact that the pointer-to-member can point (in general case) to a member of another class. In this case expression like `(this->*m)()` has no meaning, because member `m` can be declared like `void (D::*m)();`, and we need to use object of class D, not C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, _"There's probably a rationale somewhere in old discussions"_ - and that's the question - what is it :)